# LinkedLists, building a toString method for custom linked list class

Tags: java, linked-list, tostring

I'm struggling with completing this `toString()` method within my linked list class called `LString`

The class creates an LString object that mimics String and StringBuilder with a linked list rather than an array. It creates strings out of linked lists.

Here is the code for the method:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder result    = new   StringBuilder();


    node curr = front;
    while   (curr   !=  null){
        result.append(curr.data);
        curr = curr.next;

    }


    return result.toString();
}
```

I have tried several different things, and I think I'm close to figuring it out. But I can't move forward from this error message:

```
Running constructor, length, toString tests (10 tests)
Starting tests: .......E.E
Time: 0.009

There were 2 failures:
1) t11aLStringOfStringToString[1](LStringTest$LStringOfStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: LString("ab").toString() is wrong. expected:<[a]b> but was:<[]b>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringOfStringTest.t11aLStringOfStringToString(LStringTest.java:221)
        ... 10 more
2) t11aLStringOfStringToString[2](LStringTest$LStringOfStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: LString("This is a long string.").toString() is wrong. expected:<[This is a long string].> but was:<[].>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringOfStringTest.t11aLStringOfStringToString(LStringTest.java:221)
        ... 10 more

Test Failed! (2 of 10 tests failed.)

Test failures: abandoning other phases.
```

The `LString` class uses another class, LStringTest.java to do various tests. This error message is from running LStringTest.java, but the method that I'm working on is within LString. It is the, `LString("ab").toString() is wrong` bit.

For some context, here is the rest of my class:

```
public class LString    {

     // 2. Fields
     node   front;
     //node tail;
     int size;

     // 1. Node class

    private class node {

        char data;
        node next;

        //constructors
        //1. default
        public node (){
        }

        //2. data
        public node (char newData){
             this.data = newData;
        }

        //3. data + next
        public node (char newData, node newNext){
             this.data = newData;
             this.next = newNext;
        }


   }
     // 3. Constructors
    public LString(){
        this.size = 0;
        this.front = null;
    }
   public LString(String original) {

      for (int i =0; i < original.length(); i++) {

         this.front = new node(original.charAt(i));
      }
      this.size = original.length();

   }

    //  4.  Methods
   public int length() {
      return this.size;
   }
   public int compareTo(LString anotherLString) {
      return 0;
   }
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (other == null || !(other instanceof LString)) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         LString otherLString = (LString)other;
         return true;
      }
   }
   public char charAt(int index) {
      return 'a';
   }
   public void setCharAt(int index, char ch) {
      ch = 'a';
   }
   public LString substring(int start, int end) {
      return null;
   }
   public LString replace(int start, int end, LString lStr) {
      return null;
   }

    //append
    public void append(char data){

        this.size++;

        if  (front == null){
             front =    new node(data);
             return;
        }

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr.next != null){
             curr   = curr.next;
        }

        curr.next = new node(data);

    }

    //prepend
    public void prepend (char data){
        /*node temp = new   node(data);
        temp.next = front;
        front   = temp;*/

        front   = new   node(data, front);
        size++;
    }

    //delete
    public void delete(int index){
    //assume    that index is valid
        if  (index == 0){
             front =    front.next;
        } else {
             node   curr = front;
             for (int i = 0; i <    index   - 1; i++){
                curr = curr.next;
             }
             curr.next = curr.next.next;
        }
        size--;

    }

    //toString
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result    = new   StringBuilder();
        //result.append('[');

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr   !=  null){

         //result.append('[');
            result.append(curr.data);
         curr = curr.next;
         //result.append(']');
            //if (curr.next != null){

            //}

        }

        //result.append(']');
        return result.toString();
    }

    //add   (at an index)
    public void add(int index,  char data){
         if (index == 0){
              front = new node(data, front);
         }  else {
              node curr = front;
              for   (int i =    0;  i < index - 1;  i++){
                    curr = curr.next;
              }
              curr.next = new   node(data, curr.next);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this program and stepped through the necessary parts line-by-line? Simple fix really..

Comment: toString is only one problem in this code.  Your LString constructor is also broken

Answer (score 1):

In the LString constructor you are only reassigning a new char to the front each time it goes through the loop. When it finishes constructing the LString it will only have one front node of the last char in the original String.

You can assign the front outside of the loop and make a temporary 'current' node to move through and assign chars. Something like this:

```
//This will assign the first char to the front
this.front = new node(original.charAt(0);

//Create a temporary current node
node curr = this.front;

//Since you already have the first node set up you can start i at 1
for (int i = 1; original.length(); i++) {

   //Assign the char to the next node
   curr.next = new node(original.charAt(i));

   //Change current to the next node, this way it wont just rewrite the same node
   curr = curr.next;

}
```

This was the main problem as far as I can tell, so there is nothing wrong the the toString method itself.

Hope this helps, Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue that I'm seeing is that your LString constructor is using the wrong node constructor when generating nodes for new string.  As a result the linked-list nodes aren't actually linked to one another.  Basically you need to change

```
this.front = new node(original.charAt(i));
```

to

```
this.front = new node(original.charAt(i), this.front);
```

Of course, you will still have `this.front` pointed at the last character, rather than the first, so you might want to change the order in which you parse the input.  Another, perhaps better, option would be to use your own `append` method in the constructor to avoid code duplication.  The way it's implemented now, though, you'll end up with an O(n^2) algorithm, since each append will iterate through the entire list.

Obviously a lot of the rest of LString is also unimplemented (charAt always returns 'a'...) , so this isn't going to be your only problem.